# Unable to ping any other device except gateway

Tags: networking, raspberry-pi

I create a Hotspot Wifi with a First Raspberry to connect to second Raspberry and my computer.

My First Raspberry is also connect to internet by ethernet connection.

My problem is :
My second Raspberry, can't ping my computer and internet like [www.google.fr](http://www.google.fr).
While my computer can ping the First and Second Raspberry and go to internet.

Below, the ip tables in my Raspberry server :

*

```
*pi@raspberrypi:~ $ /sbin/route -n Kernel IP routing table Destination  Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    202    0        0 eth0
10.0.10.0       0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     304    0        0 wlan1
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     202    0        0 eth0*
```

- 

My computer ip address is : 10.0.10.238

My second Raspberry ip address is : 10.0.10.10

And my First Raspberry configuration is :

```
*interface=wlan1 # Listening interface
dhcp-range=10.0.10.2,10.0.10.255,255.255.255.0,24h
                # Pool of IP addresses served via DHCP
domain=wlan     # Local wireless DNS domain
address=/gw.wlan/10.0.10.1
                # Alias for this router*
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you configured the iptables on your "First" PI to forward the packets ? You´ll usually need to enable the forwarding since it´ll drop them by default (from my knowledge)

Comment: @FabianZimbalev If you're speak about "/proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward" then yes it's at 1.